# Is there any way to organise movies into separate playlists in iPad Videos / iTunes?

Tags: itunes, ipad

I come from an Android background where dragging movies in folders across remains in that same format from laptop to tablet.

Now, on my Macbook Pro, I drag TV series folders with their sub-folders into my iTunes. Everything arrives completely disorganized and jumbled all together.

This makes it painful to find my way from series to series when I previously had neatly arranged folders within folders.

I also don't want to have to spend time dragging each file into place, checking against the original organised structure.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Click create new playlist folder in the bottom left hand corner
2.1) Name the folder 
3) Click new playlist
3.1) Name the playlist
4) Drag folder in finder to playlist
5.) Sync with iPad 
6.) Click include playlists in the Movies window and select playlist to be included.

Comment: Nope, this has not helped the iPad Videos app make anything less disorganised. Everything is still all over the place.